# How to retrieve multiple substrings of a string and write them into one string in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers, formatting, string-formatting

How can I split a `const char *` string in the fastest possible way.

```
char *inputStr="abcde";
char buff[500];
```

I would like to have in buffer the following formatted string, format of which must be:

```
IN('a','ab','abc','abcd','abcde')
```

I'm learning C and new to the language. I have no clue where to start on this splitting problem.

Comment: A loop would work very well here.

Comment: You should not call this splitting. You just take more and more characters, in only one part. Splitting a string is separating two parts based on a chosen criteria

Comment: Do not use both [tag:c] and [tag:c++] tags. These are different languages.

Comment: I'm learning C and new to the language. I have no clue where to start on this splitting problem.

Comment: You are probably following a course which has handed you out materials. Study them as most assignments in a course or tutorial are done based on stuff already learned.

Comment: @DaveGreeko - You should consider thinking of this as a 'copying problem', rather than a 'splitting problem'. It's important to know just how you'd like the output - From your description, I assume you expect 'a',0x0,'a','b',0x0,'a','b','c',0x0,'a','b','c','d',0x0,'a','b','c','d','e',0x0 - I.e all results in a single 20 char buffer, separated by NULL terminators. Is this interpretation correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this particularly "fast", it seems like it's quite heavily limited since it needs to iterate over the source string many times.

I'd do something like:

```
void permute(char *out, const char *in)
{
  const size_t in_len = strlen(in);
  char *put;

  strcpy(out, "IN(");
  put = out + 3;
  for(i = 1; i < in_len; ++i)
  {
    if(i > 1)
     *put++ = ',';
    *put++ = '\'';
    memcpy(put, in, i);
    put += i;
    *put++ = '\'';
  }
  *put++ = ')';
  *put++ = '\0';
}
```

Note that this doesn't protect against buffer overrun in the output.

Comment: Awesome just looped through this code 10,000,000 times and it took on my machine an avg of 5 seconds. However, the strcat and strncat version took over 200 seconds. Not a scientific benchmark but it served the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

To give you a start, consider the following code:

```
char buffer[64];
const char str[] = "abcde";

for (size_t i = 1; i <= strlen(str); ++i)
{
    strncpy(buffer, str, i);
    buffer[i] = '\0';  /* Make sure string is terminated */
    printf("i = %lu, buffer = \"%s\"\n", i, buffer);
}
```

The above code should print

```
i = 1, buffer = "a"
i = 2, buffer = "ab"
i = 3, buffer = "abc"
i = 4, buffer = "abcd"
i = 5, buffer = "abcde"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`strcpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy), [`strcat`/`strncat`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) and a simple loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char* inputStr = "abcde";
    char buff[500];
    // start the formatted string:
    strcpy(buff,"IN(");
    int i, len = strlen(inputStr);
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        strcat(buff, "'");
        strncat(buff, inputStr, i + 1);
        strcat(buff, "'");
        // if it is not last token:
        if (i != len - 1)
            strcat(buff, ",");
    }
    // end the formatted string:
    strcat(buff,")");
    printf("%s", buff);
    return 0;
}
```

outputs the desired `IN('a','ab','abc','abcd','abcde')`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something like this in C++:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    const char *inputStr = "abcde"; //const to remove warning of deprecated conversion
    char buff[500];

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < (int) strlen(inputStr); i++) {   //cast it to int to remove 
                                   // warning of comparison between signed and unsigned
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            buff[count++] = inputStr[j];
        }
        buff[count++] = ',';
    }
    buff[--count] = '\0';
    cout << buff;
    return 0;
}
```

Output - a,ab,abc,abcd,abcde